# Does the prohibition from Devarim 22:11 relate to קַ֔יִן Qayin and הֶ֨בֶל Hevel?

Tags: clothing, parshat-devarim, deuteronomy

Does the prohibition לֹ֤א תִלְבַּשׁ֙ שַֽׁעַטְנֵ֔ז צֶ֥מֶר וּפִשְׁתִּ֖ים יַחְדָּֽו from **Devarim 22:11** relate to קַ֔יִן Qayin and הֶ֨בֶל Hevel?

- **What sources (besides the two provided) validate this concept?**

---

**Commentary by Daat Zkenim - Devarim 22:11** [ https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.11?with=Daat%20Zkenim&lang=bi&aliyot=0 ]:

> "An alternate reason offered for this prohibition of mixing wool and linen, is that Kayin’s offering consisted of linen, and Hevel’s of wool, and is therefore a reminder of jealousy and hatred, the opposite of what the Torah stands for."

---

**"Living Torah: Why Can’t We Wear Wool and Linen?"** [ https://unitedwithisrael.org/living-torah-why-cant-we-wear-wool-and-linen/ ]

> "It is explained that Shatnez is a decree that defies logic and there is no given reason for observing it. Nevertheless, we are told that it represents and recalls the fight between Cain and Abel. Cain brought an offering of the ground, from his flax (which is “linen”), and Cain brought an offering of wool from his sheep. Cain’s offering was rejected because it was of low quality and was not given wholeheartedly. Abel’s was accepted because it was both of high quality and given with sincerity. Cain became jealous and killed his brother. Hence, it can be said that it was a mixture of wool and linen that brought about the first murder in history. Therefore, we may not wear a garment made of wool and linen."

Comment: I seem to remember Rashi on Chumash mentions this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 21:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.21.6?lang=bi&with=Share&lang2=en) says:

ר' יהושע בן קרחה אומר, אמר הקב"ה אל יתערבו מנחת קין והבל לעולם שמא חס ושלום יתערבו
בארג בגד, שנאמר לא תלבש שעטנז וגו', אפילו היא מרוככת לא תעלה עליך

Rabbi Yehoshua ben Korcha said, Hakodosh Boruch Hu said, that the gifts of Kayin and Hevel should forever not be mixed, perhaps they will be mixed in clothing, it says "Lo Silbash Shaatnez" if it is mixed you should not put it on you.

Comment: Translation please